# How do I annotate a dynamodb mapper with a secondary index?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, annotations, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm trying to setup a Subscription table in dynamodb to keep track of who a user subscribes to.

I have a table for Subscriptions with 2 String attributes, SubscriberID and UserID and would be setup like so (using names for simplicity):

```
[SubscriberID] ------ [UserID]

    Dave   ------ Steve

    Dave   ------ Josh

    Dave   ------ Cam

    Cam    ------ Dave

    Cam    ------ Justin
```

So it would be interpreted as: Dave subscribes to Steve, Josh, and Cam. Cam subscribes to Dave and Justin.. pretty simple.

I have a primary key with SubscriberID as the partition key so I can query a user's subscriptions. I also have a secondary index called "getSubscribers" which has UserID as the partition key so I can query a user's subscribers.

Each time I try to save a dynamodb mapper object it doesn't show up in my Subscriptions table, but my other tables w/ only 1 primary key are entering fine.

I'm almost positive my problem is with my annotations on my Subscriber class, I've tried researching how this would properly be setup, the best I came up with was this

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "starter-mobilehub-1604839252-Subscriptions ")
public class Subscription {

  private String SubscriberID;
  private String UserID;

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "SubscriberID")
  public String getSubscriberID() {return SubscriberID;}
  public void setSubscriberID(String UserID) {this.SubscriberID = UserID;}

  @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "getSubscribers", attributeName = "UserID")
  public String getUserID() {return UserID;}
  public void setUserID(String UserID) {this.UserID = UserID;}

}
```

I know that it's probably wrong, does anyone know how these annotations are supposed to be setup right? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? 
My idea was to basically duplicate the table definition and use a different hash key for each one, however I am not sure this would work and also it seems as a hacky solution

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out somehow. I removed the GSI and it still wasn't updating to the table. So I removed and re-added it without a GSI and it worked, then added the GSI and it still works.

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: code snippet, please?